# Where did the "Other Settings" go in Android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, settings, android-studio-2.0

I can't seem to find the menu

> Settings > Other Settings

Where is it hiding? ;)

[image: Android Studio Settings]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a project, update your plugins. You simply don't have anything to configure.

Comment: "Other Settings" appeared after opening a project. The setting's window header displayed "Settings" and not "Default Settings" when having an opened project.